# Reconnecting QTcpServer

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm writing client-server app, which uses QTcpSocket and QTcpServer. 
Here are the disconnected() slots:

**server:**

```
    void testServer::disconnected()
{
    socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    qDebug() << " - CLIENT DISCONNECTED";
    socket->disconnectFromHost();

    if(server->isListening())
    {
        server->close();
        qDebug() << " - SERVER CLOSED";
    }
}
```

**client:**

```
void testClient::disconnected()
{
    qDebug() << " - SERVER DISCONNECTED";
    tcpSocket->disconnectFromHost();
}
```

I face strange behavior when I try to imitate possible crashes when both sides are connected: when I close the server I can always reconnect to the new one with my client. But if I close the client while being connected, I can reconnect the server to the client just two times. And no more.

On the third "establish connection - restart the client - connect to the server" routine I always fail.

> QTcpServer::newConnection()

signal is emitted, but

> server->hasPendingConnections()

returns false, so I can't assign the socket with

> socket = server->nextPendingConnection()

What's the problem with reconnecting QTcpServer?
Also, server and client always runs on const ports, e.x. 1234 for server and 4321 for client. Can this be the issue?

Comment: What is [maxPandingConnections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#maxPendingConnections) on server? Why you are doing `server->close()` if you need a reconnect feature?

Answer (score 1):

`server->close()` ends the operation of the server. It won't accept any more connections, and any pending ones will be immediately closed as well. There's a race between the emission of the `newConnection` signal and the use of `hasPendingConnections`. The latter provides a correct answer - the server is closed at that point.

C.f. the documentation:

> `void QTcpServer::close()`
>
> Closes the server. The server will no longer listen for incoming
>   connections.